# Make the 'Profile' -> 'Top tags' details clearer please (mainly 'score')

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, tag-score, top-tag

How can someone know what `score` means in a user's profile page ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/541136/aaron-hall))? (We shouldn't rely on users searching the web. It should be clear here.)

The `50 posts %` is a bit clearer (though not completely clear), but the order should be changed to `50% posts` or perhaps something else.

Comment: I always thought score was pretty self-explanatory, what's less clear is that the tag score only comes from answers, but that's already addressed in the tooltip so... I see no problem

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing at all clear about `50 posts %`. It isn't even grammatically correct. I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: perfectly seems clear me to. Fuss what's the about?

Comment: What would you propose it says instead of "score"? "Upvotes minus downvotes"?